# android activity cannot bind to service

Tags: android, service, android-activity, tabs, bind

I managed to connect an activity to a service and it runs ok. This is my first activity in the application. However, if i progress (with or without binding to the service in the first activity), the next activity (resides in a tab) will not bind to the service.

note that if i make the trouble-making activity to be my first in the app, it works fine.

any hints on what might cause the pb? the code in the 2 activities is the same. 
might it be because of the tabbing?
do i need to setup any particular intent filtering stuff>? (i only have the default intent filtering that comes with the template)

Thanks.
Alex

Answer (score 1):

apparently this is a known issue:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2665

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can use getApplicationContext().{bindService,unbindService}